# Medium editor showing "placeholder"

Tags: 7

I'm trying to use the [Medium module](https://www.drupal.org/project/medium), but for some reason it just shows "placeholder" when I click on the **Configuration > Content Authoring > Medium** Editor. Could you point me to any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

That module has not been finished, yet. [The function that should return the form for the settings of that module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/medium/tree/medium.module?h=7.x-1.x#n45) doesn't even allow to set any settings; it just output that *Placeholder* text you see.

```
  $form = array();

  // @TODO: Allow users to choose the image style used for media embeds.
  // @TODO: Allow users to choose which media plugins should be exposed.

  $form['whatever'] = array(
    '#markup' => 'Placeholder'
  );

  return $form;
```

The module is in a alpha state; don't consider it ready for production.